# Changing Cortana system settings

Tags: windows, cortana

I'd like to change the Cortana system settings specifically the 'Hey Cortana' setting.
However, the two most relevant resources ([Windows universal samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) and [WinAPI function for system settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) don't appear to show any way to change these settings.

Perhaps I haven't looked at `SystemParametersInfo` hard enough or it doesn't support Cortana settings. So I wonder, is there any way to programmatically change these settings?

Comment: What part of "Hey, Cortana" are you trying to change? Are you trying to disable it, change the trigger phrase, etc?

Comment: [A handy image](http://cnet2.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2015/07/30/cd108e2d-4bce-4794-a3f0-211c0955ecb8/resize/770x578/95ecaa71aec7aae28982927c51c3fda7/cortana-enable.jpg) highlighting the specific setting I'm looking to toggle.